# Android - Trouble with Operators and TextView values

Tags: java, android, textview, operators

Why is the code executing when all the 3 textfields still contain "Enter Date", "Start Time" and "End Time"?

```
CharSequence x = startDateDisplay.getText();
CharSequence y = startTimeDisplay.getText();
CharSequence z = endTimeDisplay.getText();

Log.d(TAG, "validate on save: "+ x + " " + y + " " + z );

if(startDateDisplay.getText() != "Enter Date" && 
    startTimeDisplay.getText() != "Start Time" && 
    endTimeDisplay.getText() != "End Time" ) 
{
    //excecute code    
}
else
{
   Toast.makeText(this, "Please fill in all fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Where did you put this. Is it in the `onCreate`?

Comment: No, it's in a public void buttonSaveClick(View view) method which is called on a button click event.

Comment: Output from Log.d = || PH_TAG || validate on save: Enter Date Start Time End Time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For String comparison, use `String.equals()` method:

```
if(!StartDateDisplay.getText().toString().equals("Enter Date") &&
!StartTimeDisplay.getText().toString().equals("Start Time") &&
!endTimeDisplay.getText().toString().equals("End Time"))
```

Comment: Yes, that would be it! To compare Strings of textviews we need to use .toString() and  .equals().
Note: You spelt "toString" wrong, you might want to update that too, case other people need this. And thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it like this:

```
if(!startDateDisplay.getText().toString().equals("Enter Date") && 
    !startTimeDisplay.getText().toString().equals("Start Time") && 
    !endTimeDisplay.getText().toString().equals("End Time") ) {
}
```

It should work, because what you are getting now is an object per say, and what you really want is the CharSequence value from that object, which would be `'Enter Date'`, `'Start Time'`, and `'End Time'`.

Comment: Mohamed_AbdAllah answered this, you were clsoe, but thank you anyway.